# What is the difference between a borrowed and a derived Word in Linguistics?

Tags: terminology, etymology, derivation

When looking at Etymologies of words, I noticed that there are "borrowed" words and "derived" words. "Borrowed" is, I think, just taken from a different language, but what are "derived" words then? Aren't they also from other languages?

Comment: It's like inheritance; there are blood relatives, proceeding from a single ancestor, and there are relatives who've been adopted or married into the family. Cognate (from Latin _co-g(e)n-atus_ 'born together') words have the same historic source, like English _king_ and _kin_ and _kind_, all from [PIE _*gen-_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/gen.pdf). Borrowings get into the family at some point, like English picking up _gentle_, from the same root but into Latin, so that _kind_ and _gentle_ not only mean the same thing, they come from the same root. "Derived" would mean 'descent'.

Comment: "they come from the same [stem]" would be more precise. "root" as in "root of the problem" is on the one hand often conflated with "root" as in "radix", "root of a polynom", i.e. something to be infered by symbolic abduction and represented abstractly in writing, as for Semitic *tri-lateral roots* which don't exist as such in the spoken language, maybe in the mind of the speaker as a matter of cognitive syntax, which is too unreliable to serve as yard stick. E.g. *d-r-v-* maybe recognizable as the sound shape of *drive* and *drove*, but also of *derive*! "Stem" conveys the same idea, anyhow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this sense, a "derived" word is derived from something else within the same language, or a direct ancestor of that language.

For example, English "miniature" is borrowed from Italian, but "miniaturization" is derived from that (by adding pieces onto the end) within English itself.